# Inserir dados no banco Mysql recebidos de um Json

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um app e por ele envio alguns dados no formato Json, para o servidor, até ai blz, chega de boa nesse formato:
`{"credenciador":"","evento":"16","inscrito":[{"id_inscrito":"13","data_credenciado":"2016-09-23 14:39:52"}],"atividade":"8"}`

Tenho que receber esses dados e adicionar no banco de dados(Mysql), o problema é que não vai de jeito nenhum, se eu tira o 'INSERT' o código funciona de boa, mas com o 'INSERT' da erro, acredito que meu sql esta dando um resultado nulo por algum motivo, alguém já teve esse problema ou tem ideia do que pode ser? Segue abaixo o script onde trato os valores Json:

```
<?php
    include('../admin/config.php');
    function processaCredenciamento($credenciamento){
        $credenciamento = json_decode($credenciamento);
        $credenciador = $credenciamento->credenciador;
        $evento = $credenciamento->evento;
        $inscritos = $credenciamento->inscrito;

        $inscritos = json_decode($inscritos);

        $queryinsert = "insert into credenciamento(credenciador, inscrito, evento, data_credenciamento, data_envio) values ";

        foreach ($inscritos as $inscrito) {
            $queryinsert = "(".$credenciador.",".$inscrito->id_inscrito.",".$evento.",".$inscrito->data_credenciado.",now()),";
        }
        $queryinsert = substr($queryinsert, 0, -1);

        $credenciamento = mysql_query($queryinsert);


    }

    if($_POST){
         echo '{"retorno":true}';
         processaCredenciamento($_POST['credenciamento']);
         $filename = "retorno_credenciamento.txt";
         file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['credenciamento']);
    }
```

CÓDIGO FUNCIONAL:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

if($_POST){
        $credenciamento = json_decode($_POST['credenciamento']);
        $credenciador = $credenciamento->credenciador;
        $evento = $credenciamento->evento;
        $atividade = $credenciamento->atividade;
        $inscritos = $credenciamento->inscrito;

        foreach ($inscritos as $in){
            $insert_cred = "INSERT INTO credenciamento (evento, atividade, inscrito, data_credenciameno, data_envio) VALUES (".$evento.", ".$atividade.", ".$in->id_inscrito.", '".$in->data_credenciado."', now())";
            $credenciamento = mysql_query($insert_cred, $conexao) or die (mysql_error());
        }

         echo '{"retorno":true}';
         $filename = "retorno_credenciamento.txt";
         file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['credenciamento']);
}

?>
```

Comment: Faça assim para exibir um possível erro, `$credenciamento = mysql_query($queryinsert) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Lembre que todos campos varchar ou date precisa estar entre aspas simples.

Comment: Mesmo que eu coloque apenas os campos com int ainda assim não vai

Comment: Aparece algum erro com a modificação do código?

Comment: @JonathanWillian removi novamente o [resolvido] do título. Para fechar o assunto, basta o _accept_ (o V verdinho, que você pôs na resposta dada), não precisa (e nem deve) mexer na postagem inicial nestes casos.

Comment: Opa desculpa, força do hábito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usar o decode, utilize o true depois do JSON para transformar em um array, acredito ser mais prático.

`$inscrito = json_decode($inscritos,true);`

Então ao acessar o conteúdo utilize `$inscrito['id_inscrito']`, caso não use o true após a decodificação, acesse o conteúdo usando `$inscrito->{'id_inscrito'}`.

Caso mesmo com as modificações não funcione, após montar sua query, antes de executar, imprima ela e tente executar direto no banco para ver a mensagem que dá, desta forma você pode ficar tentando alterar a query até achar onde está o erro, desta forma você tem certeza que é um erro no mySql e não no PHP.

Você pode fazer por exemplo: um `die($queryinsert);`

**Edit:** Altere a declaração das variáveis

```
    $credenciamento = json_decode($credenciamento,true);
    $credenciador = $credenciamento['credenciador'];
    $evento = $credenciamento['evento'];
    $inscritos = $credenciamento['inscrito'];

  // $inscritos = json_decode($inscritos); creio que está linha não será mais necessária
```

Comment: Agora deu certo amigo, só que ainda assim não to conseguindo pega os valores do $inscrito, de esse erro:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in. Mesmo colocando o 'true'

Comment: Ah sim, é que no primeiro decode você já transforma em objeto, vou editar a resposta

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado! Vou posta como ficou o código na atualização